# AWS Binpack placement strategy resulting in issues during instance autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs, autoscaling, bin-packing

Here is the scenario:

We are running Docker containers in an `AWS ECS cluster`. Previously, we were not using any placement strategy for containers. For minimizing the number of instances within the cluster, we tried introducing binpack placement strategy. After that, whenever we try to deploy containers multiple at a time(in parallel), the instances do not autoscale and stay at the minimum limit set for them. We are not sure what went wrong. Most of the services are not reaching steady state due to this. For now, we have removed binpack, and again it has started working perfectly and we are able to deploy in parallel.

Though, there is no issue when we deploy one service at a time and everything seems fine.

We are using `t2.large type instances` in our case.
Instance auto-scaling is happening based on memory reservation(>80% for 1 minute).

Looking at the graph, we can check memory threshold is not getting reached. It `crosses >80 threshold` only for few seconds, and then again goes down. This is a strange behaviour according to me.

Does binpack does not support t2 type instances? Or is there any other case I am missing?